# ng-select component has a gap between input box and items

Tags: html, css, angular, css-grid, angular-ngselect

I have app that uses the [@ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) library. I am also using a component that expands when called upon. If I expand the drop down everything works, but if I have some items in my other component my drop down has a gap that corresponds to the height of the other component. I am using css grid to align the 2 horizontally as seen below. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2gccn) is a stackblitz. Click "New Query" in the drop down then "Rule" to add rules. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div class="quick-filters form-inline">
  <ng-select style="width: 100%;" appearance="outline" [searchable]="false" [(ngModel)]="filterType" groupBy="group"
    (change)="onFilterTypeSelect($event)" [items]="filterTypes" bindLabel="name">
  </ng-select>
  <div *ngIf="showQuickQuery" class="input-add-on">
    <query-builder class="input-add-on-field" [formControl]='queryCtrl' [config]='queryConfig' [allowRuleset]="false">
      <ng-container
        *queryButtonGroup="let ruleset=addRuleSet; let addRule=addRule; let addRuleSet=addRuleSet; let removeRuleSet=removeRuleSet">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="ruleset.rules == 0" (click)="onSaveFilter()"><i
              class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="color: #00BFFF;"></i> Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addRule()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Rule</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="ruleset.rules == 0" (click)="onValueSelect()"><i
              class="fa fa-play" style="color: #32CD32;"></i> Apply</button>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *queryInput="let rule; type: 'date-range'">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rule.value" placement="bottom right" bsDaterangepicker
          [bsConfig]="bsConfig" />
      </ng-container>
    </query-builder>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .quick-filters {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". .";
    grid-gap: 2px;
  }
  .input-add-on {
    display: flex;
  }

  .input-add-on-field {
    flex: 1;
  }
```

[image: Gap]

Comment: It would be useful to have stackblitz on this. Makes it easy to debug.

Comment: I'd assume it's something related to the positioning. Try to put the ng-select inside a div that has `position:relative`. See how that goes.

As @MaihanNijat mentioned, it would be easier for us to fix it if you create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @MaihanNijat I edited and added a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a div with `position:relative` fixed the issue. Thanks for the help in the comments. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ygvk1?file=src/app/app.component.html) is an updated stackblitz. I left the original to see the problem.